# Strings passed to fmt.Sprintf are Enclosed in Square Brackets

Tags: go, format-string

Given the following code snippet

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Message string

const (
    ConnectRepositoryError Message = "failed to connect %s repository"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ConnectRepositoryError.M("user"))
}

func (m Message) M(args ...string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(string(m), args)
}
```

... why does `fmt.Sprintf` enclose the specified string (`user`) in square brackets?

```
failed to connect [user] repository
```

I'd expect this output instead:

```
failed to connect user repository
```

Answer (score 8):

Because inside `Message.M()` you call [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf), to which you pass the format string `string(m)` and a **single** argument `args` being a string slice. And slices are formatted like: the elements separated by space, enclosed in square brackets. And since you pass a single value to `M()`, it'll be a one-element slice, printed like `[user]`.

Instead you want to pass `args` as the variadic parameter to `fmt.Sprintf()`, so use `...`.

Of course this will be a compile time-error because `fmt.Sprintf()` expects `...interface{}` and `...string` does not qualify. You have to change the parameter of `M` to be `...interface{}`:

```
func (m Message) M(args ...interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(string(m), args...)
}
```

With this change output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FGN5OLgyyao)):

```
failed to connect user repository
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument list for variable argument functions is a slice. When you print a slice, it is printed as `[value value ...]`.

You should convert the strings to an `[]interface{}`, and use the following syntax to pass all elements of the slice:

```
func (m Message) M(args ...string) string {
    iargs:=make([]interface{},0,len(args))
    for _,x:=range args {
      iargs=append(iargs, x)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(string(m), iargs...)
}
```